# An incorrect clicked item in the new activity from RecycleView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have got a problem in my code:
I cannot see a properly clicked item in the new activity "CrimePagerActivity" from `RecycleView`.
I can see another item from the list in this activity (`ViewPager`).

I have found the issue here, in this row of code:

```
Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mCrime.getId());
```

I get an incorrect item from `mCrime.getId()`.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to fix it.
Maybe someone can help me?

My code and some of my layouts are below.

**Crime.java**

```java
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Crime{

    private UUID mId;
    private String mTitle;
    private Date mDate;
    private boolean mSolved;
    private boolean mRequiresPolice;

    public Crime() {
        // Generate unique identifier
        this(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    public Crime(UUID id) {
        mId = id;
        mDate = new Date();
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        mDate = date;
    }

    public boolean isSolved() {
        return mSolved;
    }

    public void setSolved(boolean solved) {
        mSolved = solved;
    }

    public boolean isRequiresPolice() {
        return mRequiresPolice;
    }

    public void setRequiresPolice(boolean requiresPolice) {
        mRequiresPolice = requiresPolice;
    }
}
```

**CrimeLab.java**

```java
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Context;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;


public class CrimeLab {

    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    public static CrimeLab get(Context context) {
        if (sCrimeLab == null) {
            sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(context);
        }
        return sCrimeLab;
    }

    private CrimeLab(Context context){

        mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Crime crime = new Crime();
            crime.setTitle("Crime #" + i);
            crime.setSolved(i % 2 == 0); 
            if (i % 4 == 0 ) {crime.setRequiresPolice(true);}
            else {crime.setRequiresPolice(false);}
            mCrimes.add(crime);
        }

    }

    public List<Crime> getCrimes() {
        return mCrimes;
    }

    public  Crime getCrime(UUID id){

        for (Crime crime : mCrimes){
            int rez = id.compareTo(crime.getId());
            if (crime.getId().equals(id)){
                return crime;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**CrimeListFragment.java**

```java
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int REQUEST_CRIME = 1;

    private static final int NOT_REQUIRES_POLICE = 0;
    private static final int REQUIRES_POLICE = 1;

    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    private CrimeAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDateTextView;
    private ImageView mSolvedImageView;
    private Button mButtonCallPolice;
    private Crime mCrime;
    private CharSequence mDateFormat;
    private  int layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container,
                false);
        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateUI();
        return view;
    }

    private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


         public CrimeHolder(int layout, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent ) {


            super(inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false));

            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
            mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
            mSolvedImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);

            if (itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_police)!=null) {
                mButtonCallPolice = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_police);
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bind(Crime crime) {

            mCrime = crime;
            mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
            mDateFormat = DateFormat.format("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy", mCrime.getDate());

            mDateTextView.setText(mDateFormat);
            mSolvedImageView.setVisibility(mCrime.isSolved() ? View.VISIBLE :
                    View.GONE);

            if(mCrime.isRequiresPolice()){
                mButtonCallPolice.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mCrime.getId());
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CRIME);
        }

    }

    private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder> {


        private List<Crime> mCrimes;
        public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
            mCrimes = crimes;
        }

       @Override
        public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

            if (viewType==1) { layout =  R.layout.list_item_crime_police;}

            else {             layout =  R.layout.list_item_crime;       }

            return new CrimeHolder (layout, layoutInflater, parent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position) {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
            holder.bind(crime);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }


        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);

            return (crime.isRequiresPolice()) ? 1 : 0;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes);
            mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CRIME) {
            // Обработка результата
        }

    }

    public void returnResult() {
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    }

}
```

**CrimePagerActivity.java**

```java
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CrimePagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.crime_id";

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID crimeId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CrimePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);

        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.crime_view_pager);

        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),mCrimes);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++) {
            if (mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private List<Crime> mCrimesCopy;

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Crime> mCrimesParametr) {
            //super(fm);
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
            this.mCrimesCopy = mCrimesParametr;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCrimesCopy.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Crime crime = mCrimesCopy.get(position);
            return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_crime_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crime_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**fragment_crime.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_label"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint"
        android:inputType=""
        android:autofillHints="" />
    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_details_label"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/crime_solved_label"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item_crime_police.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/crime_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_solved"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/crime_date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_solved" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/call_police"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/call_police"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_date" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_solved" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list_item_crime.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/crime_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_solved"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/crime_date"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_solved" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_solved"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_crime_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

**activity_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problematic Code :

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mCrime.getId());
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CRIME);
        }
```

`mCrime.getId()` will return the `id` of **most recently binded `mCrime` object and NOT the one that was clicked.** To get the `id` of `mCrime` that was clicked, you need to use `getAdapterPosition()` method which will return the position of currently clicked item.
Now, your improved `onClick()` method may look like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), CrimeLab.get(requireActivity()).getCrimes().get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CRIME);
        }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have used your answer and I have changed it a little.                                      Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(),
                    CrimeLab.get(requireActivity()).getCrimes().get((getAdapterPosition())).getId());

Comment: But I have another problem in my Recycleview.
If I scroll this list with the mouse wheel my items in the list look like unordered. I do not understand , why?

Comment: Sorry that I missed a call  to `getId()`, it was my original intention but I forgot it while writing answer xD. Anyway, if you think, my hard work in looking all of your code deserves a reward, please accept this as an answer. I am not sure how to fix your second problem but last time when I had such problem, I fixed it by moving `Adapter` class to a separate file and `ViewHolder` class was inside that file. You can log different values to see what might have been wrongdoing here.

Comment: 2cgb_pandey , thank you very much for your help and all your efforts . I will try to do that you have written in the comment.

Comment: And, I forgot one thing, you need to create new question for your new problem. Other coming at SO to find answer for that question will not know if the answers are in the comment. That's why create a separate thread for it, I will try to figure out where it went wrong in my code, which I think will work for you too. That time, I had 2 working adapters: 1 simple `adapter` that was an direct object of `RecyclerView.Adapter` class and another was `custom adapter` which extended it. I switched from 1st to 2nd adapter and the problem was gone. I never looked to resolve it later.

Comment: Post a new question and leave the link here in the comment.

Comment: this is my new topic about this issue.                                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285239/an-unordered-recycleview-list-after-scrolling

Comment: 2 cgb_pandey. Hi! If you know how to resolve this problem I glad to see you and to read your posts  in my new topic.The link is in the prior comment.  I am a novice in Java.

Comment: Sorry to reply late, lately I lost my internet connection thats why I am not able to use my laptop. I am replying from mobile now. Within a day or two, it should get fixed and then I will reply as soon as possible with answers. Till then wait to see if someone else will reply.